# Google place api call on AutoCompleteTextView in Appcompactivity - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api

How can I get suggestions of places in EditText using Google place API?

Comment: Do you know how to get the list of places from Google place api?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you go through Google's [get started guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) first. Then add an `AutocompleteSupportFragment` to your activity following the [place autocomplete guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment). See the code below:

```
// Initialize the SDK
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");

// Create a new Places client instance
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

// Specify the types of place data to return.
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you get started!